# Rename Files in Multiple Directories to the Name of the Parent Directory

Tags: bash, directory, find, rename, mv

In my directories I have multiple files named content. I need to rename them using the exact name of the parent directory, move it outside and delete the parent directory.

The tricky part is the parent directory name formats are a.txt , b.pdf , c.mp3 so the file content needs to be renamed content.txt , content.pdf , content.mp3 afterwards moved outside and the directory should be deleted.

```
ex;
INPUT

a.txt/content
b.pdf/content
c.mp3/content

OUTPUT

a.txt
b.pdf
c.mp3
```

I used this find command and gives the desired echo output out I'm not sure where to go from there.

```
find . -type d -not -empty -exec echo mv \{\}/content \{\} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving the files with an `.bak` extension in an intermediate step and then renaming to desired name:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%/*}".bak' _ {} \; \
       -exec bash -c 'rm -r "${1%/*}"' _ {} \; && rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
```

**Example:**

```
% tree                                                    
.
├── a.txt
│   └── content
├── b.pdf
│   └── content
└── c.mp3
    └── content   

% find . -mindepth 2 -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%/*}".bak' _ {} \; -exec bash -c 'rm -r "${1%/*}"' _ {} \; && rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak

% tree
.
├── a.txt
├── b.pdf
└── c.mp3
```

Comment: the code created the files a.txt.bak , b.pdf.bak and c.mp3.bak but did not rename the files to the original extensions

Comment: @Learner The `rename` at the end does the final renaming e.g. `a.txt.bak` to `a.txt`....check if you have `rename` command..

Comment: I do have the rename command. It gives the error Can't rename *.bak *: No such file or directory. I think it's looking for the .bak extension in a place it does not exist.

Comment: @Learner If you followed what i have mentioned, it should work..check my example..

Comment: I understand. I think the issue it when there are .bak files in the sub directories as well. What your be the && rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak command for suck situation?

Comment: @Learner The `rename` would just remove last `.bak` portion..again hard to say without seeing real contents..

Comment: i managed to slow that part of the issue. I ran this command separately to remove the .bak files and rename them. #find . -name "*.bak" -exec rename 's/\.bak$//' '{}' \;

Comment: @Learner hmmmm..that's the easiest way :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a for loop in a small script.

```
#!/bin/bash
DESTINATION=/home/whatever
for dir in *; do
    if [[ -e $dir/content ]]; then
         mv $dir/content $DESTINATION/conent.${dir##*.} && rm -rf $dir
    fi
done
```

The && will make sure that the directory is only removed after the rename was successful.